# Get rid of preview warning when with gradle compileJava task?

Tags: java, gradle, java-21, preview-feature

I configured my Gradle build as follows:

```kotlin
tasks {
    val preview = "--enable-preview"

    withType<JavaCompile> {
        options.compilerArgs.add(preview)
        options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:preview")
    }

    withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        jvmArgs = jvmArgs!! + preview
    }

    withType<JavaExec> {
        jvmArgs = jvmArgs!! + preview
    }
}
```

However, when I compile, I get:

```
> Task :compileJava
warning: [preview] string templates are a preview feature and may be removed in a future release.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/javac.html), `-Xlint:preview` **enables** the check for use of preview features.

Try using `-Xlint:-preview` instead; i.e.

```
    options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:-preview")
```